# Split a matrix based in col numbers in R

Tags: r, syntax, split

Hello I am trying to split a matrix based number of columns. I mean, where `input` is my matrix I want:

```
input[[1]] = column 1
input[[2]] = column 2
...
input[[k]] = column k
```

I have tried:

```
split(input, col(input1))
```

but I get:

```
input[[1]] = `All columns`
input[[2]] = `All columns`
...
input[[k]] = `All columns`
```

Comment: Are you looking for `input[, 1]`, `input[, 2]`, `input[, k]`?

Comment: Yes, to apply in a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want :-

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=10,nrow=10)
colnames(mat) <- letters[1:10]

> mat[1:5,1:5]
           a          b          c          d           e
[1,]  0.04359815 -0.5465978  1.6571901  0.5318957 -0.37368263
[2,]  0.83665905  1.4243640 -1.6846726  0.8171491  0.81519568
[3,] -1.13277616 -1.0313740 -0.6788636  1.8289980 -1.06233673
[4,] -1.18810210 -0.2438800 -1.8984680 -0.9965713  0.04258266
[5,]  1.39090518  1.1525422  0.3488335  0.3175677  1.75836945

mat <- apply(mat,2,FUN=list)

mat[[1]]
[[1]]
[1]  0.04359815  0.83665905 -1.13277616 -1.18810210  1.39090518  0.50644256
[7] -0.93980249  0.99156864 -0.18153107 -0.82254772
```